# Get the inner shape of the object from a scan of mould

Tags: modeling, modifiers, conversion

I have two scans of a hollow  object which was cut into 2 halves. the object was a mold. Now i want get the inner shape from that mold in blender. Is it possible?

Edit:
[image]

That is a plaster cast (negative) of leg. What I normally do is scan positive cast (after filling the plaster inside) and take scan it check the quality of the cast. I'm wondering whether i can eliminate this step by using blender to fill the caste and see.

what I'm trying to do this is inverse of model to mold. There are many tutorials and posts to show how to get the mold designed if we have a stl model.

In my case I have the mold, i need to get the model from it

Thanks

Comment: What mods, how are they shaped? Could you please edit your question and add more details, possibly some screenshots of what you have? Blender has good modeling tools, you most likely can, but it is impossible to know without more details. It will likely be hard, scans often have very bad topology.

Comment: Hi, I added an edit, please look and tell me if you can provide me a solution

Comment: I would duplicate the cast and delete the excess around the edge that gives the mold its outer shape. Look at it from the other side and you have the molded shape.

Comment: Sounds like all you have to do is clean up the mesh a bit, remove excess material, then make the symmetry axis planar so you can use mirror with it. You may also have to recalculate normals with `Ctrl`+`N`